# How to make group of unaligned substring after overlapping to main sequence?

Tags: r, regex, string

Is it possible to make group of unaligned substring after overlapping to main sequence in R?

Here is dummy datasets.

```
library(stringr)
seq <- "cuggg"  #This is main string
pattern <- c("cuggguu",  
             "cuggguuu",
             "cugGguu",
             "cuggga",
             "cugggaa",
             "cugggaaa",
             "cugCg")  # these are the substrings

# However I couldnt make group of unaligned substring after overlapping to main sequence 
aa <- str_extract_all(seq, pattern)
aa

# [[1]]
# character(0)
# [[2]]
# character(0)
# [[3]]
# character(0)
# [[4]]
# character(0)
# [[5]]
# character(0)
# [[6]]
# character(0)
# [[7]]
# character(0)
# [[8]]
# character(0)
```

And I would like to output datasets like below:

```
#'[ X     Y]
#'[uu     2]  
#'[uuu    1]
#'[Gguu   1]
#'[a      1]
#'[aa     1]
#'[aaa    1]
#'[Cg     1]
```

If its possible tidyverse approach is more preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you misunderstood `str_extract_all`, since it is NOT taking out the pattern and remove from the string. Probably you can try `sub` or `gsub`

```
> sub("cug{,3}", "", s)
[1] "uu"   "uuu"  "Gguu" "a"    "aa"   "aaa"  "Cg"
```

## Data

```
s <- c(
    "cuggguu",
    "cuggguuu",
    "cugGguu",
    "cuggga",
    "cugggaa",
    "cugggaaa",
    "cugCg"
)
```

Comment: After I run code it shows error it says:   "Error in is.factor(x) : object 's' not found",.

Comment: @choij sorry, I just changed the variable name. see my data in the answer.